# Lambda and loc function for dataframes with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I've this problem in my python app. I need to add a the latest column named "ValueOverlap" (I made up this values) to my dataframe with multiple conditions and calculated result.

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close | PrevHigh | PrevLow | Direction | PrevDirection | ValueOverlap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/12/1995 | 0,2879 | 0,3170 | 0,1429 | 0,1864 | 0,4475 | 0,2824 | Bearish | Bearish | 38 |
| 31/12/1996 | 0,1886 | 0,2640 | 0,1138 | 0,1172 | 0,3170 | 0,1429 | Bearish | Bearish | 13 |
| 31/12/1997 | 0,1217 | 0,3906 | 0,1205 | 0,3655 | 0,2640 | 0,1138 | Bullish | Bearish | 38 |
| 31/12/1998 | 0,3761 | 1,0536 | 0,2857 | 0,9180 | 0,3906 | 0,1205 | Bullish | Bullish | 47 |
| 31/12/1999 | 0,9364 | 1,3426 | 0,2433 | 0,2656 | 1,0536 | 0,2857 | Bearish | Bullish | 34 |
| 31/12/2000 | 0,2656 | 0,4843 | 0,2578 | 0,3911 | 1,3426 | 0,2433 | Bullish | Bearish | 47 |
| 31/12/2001 | 0,3938 | 0,4673 | 0,2386 | 0,2559 | 0,4843 | 0,2578 | Bearish | Bullish | 46 |
| 31/12/2002 | 0,2564 | 0,4466 | 0,2271 | 0,3816 | 0,4673 | 0,2386 | Bullish | Bearish | 32 |
| 31/12/2003 | 0,3848 | 1,2423 | 0,3782 | 1,1500 | 0,4466 | 0,2271 | Bullish | Bullish | 45 |
| 31/12/2004 | 1,1568 | 2,6950 | 1,1179 | 2,5675 | 1,2423 | 0,3782 | Bullish | Bullish | 37 |
| 31/12/2005 | 2,5850 | 3,3271 | 1,7914 | 3,0300 | 2,6950 | 1,1179 | Bullish | Bullish | 46 |
| 31/12/2006 | 3,0818 | 7,2486 | 2,9250 | 7,0743 | 3,3271 | 1,7914 | Bullish | Bullish | 32 |
| 31/12/2007 | 7,1168 | 7,1521 | 2,8264 | 3,0482 | 7,2486 | 2,9250 | Bearish | Bullish | 30 |
| 31/12/2008 | 3,0671 | 7,6411 | 2,7929 | 7,5261 | 7,1521 | 2,8264 | Bullish | Bearish | 36 |
| 31/12/2009 | 7,6225 | 11,6664 | 6,7946 | 11,5200 | 7,6411 | 2,7929 | Bullish | Bullish | 16 |
| 31/12/2010 | 11,6300 | 15,2393 | 11,0893 | 14,4643 | 11,6664 | 6,7946 | Bullish | Bullish | 30 |
| 31/12/2011 | 14,6214 | 25,1811 | 14,6071 | 19,0061 | 15,2393 | 11,0893 | Bullish | Bullish | 48 |
| 31/12/2012 | 19,7793 | 20,5407 | 13,7536 | 20,0364 | 25,1811 | 14,6071 | Bullish | Bullish | 48 |
| 31/12/2013 | 19,8457 | 29,9375 | 17,6268 | 27,5950 | 20,5407 | 13,7536 | Bullish | Bullish | 16 |
| 31/12/2014 | 27,8475 | 33,6350 | 23,0000 | 26,3150 | 29,9375 | 17,6268 | Bearish | Bullish | 28 |
| 31/12/2015 | 25,6525 | 29,6725 | 22,3675 | 28,9550 | 33,6350 | 23,0000 | Bullish | Bearish | 44 |
| 31/12/2016 | 28,9500 | 44,3000 | 28,6900 | 42,3075 | 29,6725 | 22,3675 | Bullish | Bullish | 20 |
| 31/12/2017 | 42,5400 | 58,3675 | 36,6475 | 39,4350 | 44,3000 | 28,6900 | Bearish | Bullish | 37 |
| 31/12/2018 | 38,7225 | 73,4925 | 35,5000 | 73,4125 | 58,3675 | 36,6475 | Bullish | Bearish | 47 |
| 31/12/2019 | 74,0600 | 138,7900 | 53,1525 | 132,6900 | 73,4925 | 35,5000 | Bullish | Bullish | 16 |
| 31/12/2020 | 133,5200 | 182,1300 | 116,2100 | 177,5700 | 138,7900 | 53,1525 | Bullish | Bullish | 16 |
| 31/12/2021 | 177,8300 | 182,9400 | 125,8700 | 129,9300 | 182,1300 | 116,2100 | Bearish | Bullish | 34 |
| 31/12/2022 | 130,2800 | 199,6200 | 124,1700 | 193,6000 | 182,9400 | 125,8700 | Bullish | Bearish | 21 |

I test with df.loc function with this code:

```
df.loc[(df['PrevDirection'] == 'Bullish') & (df['Direction'] == 'Bullish'), 'Value_Overlap'] = min((df['PrevHigh'] - df['Low']) / (df['High'] - df['Low']) * 100, (df['PrevHigh'] - df['Low']) / (df['PrevHigh'] - df['PrevLow']) * 100)
df.loc[(df['PrevDirection'] == 'Bearish') & (df['Direction'] == 'Bearish'), 'Value_Overlap'] = min((df['High'] - df['PrevLow']) / (df['High'] - df['Low']) * 100, (df['High'] - df['PrevLow']) / (df['PrevHigh'] - df['PrevLow']) * 100)
```

And with lambda funtion with this other code:

```
df['Value_Overlap'] = df.apply(lambda x: min((df['PrevHigh'] - df['Low']) / (df['High'] - df['Low']) * 100, (df['PrevHigh'] - df['Low']) / (df['PrevHigh'] - df['PrevLow']) * 100) if x['PrevDirection'] == 'Bullish' and x['Direction'] == 'Bullish' else min((df['High'] - df['PrevLow']) / (df['High'] - df['Low']) * 100, (df['High'] - df['PrevLow']) / (df['PrevHigh'] - df['PrevLow']) * 100) if x['PrevDirection'] == 'Bearish' and x['Direction'] == 'Bearish' else 0, axis=1)
```

In booth codes are the same error: `"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."`

Any idea to solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you should probably just write a full function definition to make your lambda more readable, but it looks like you are passing a `pd.Series` to `min`, which would cause this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `min` with a list of values, you have to use a vectorized min function:

```
import numpy as np

v1 = (df['PrevHigh'] - df['Low']) / (df['High'] - df['Low']) * 100
v2 = (df['PrevHigh'] - df['Low']) / (df['PrevHigh'] - df['PrevLow']) * 100
bullish = np.min([v1, v2], axis=0)

v1 = (df['High'] - df['PrevLow']) / (df['High'] - df['Low']) * 100
v2 = (df['High'] - df['PrevLow']) / (df['PrevHigh'] - df['PrevLow']) * 100
bearish = np.min([v1, v2], axis=0)

m = (df['PrevDirection'] == 'Bullish') & (df['Direction'] == 'Bullish')
df.loc[m, 'Value_Overlap'] = bullish[m]

m = (df['PrevDirection'] == 'Bearish') & (df['Direction'] == 'Bearish')
df.loc[m, 'Value_Overlap'] = bearish[m]
```

I get a result but `Value_Overlap` are clearly not the same than `ValueOverlap`:

```
>>> df.loc[:, 'Direction':]
   Direction PrevDirection  ValueOverlap  Value_Overlap
0    Bearish       Bearish            38    -151.847365
1    Bearish       Bearish            13     104.766187
2    Bullish       Bearish            38            NaN
3    Bullish       Bullish            47      13.660633
4    Bearish       Bullish            34            NaN
5    Bullish       Bearish            47            NaN
6    Bearish       Bullish            46            NaN
7    Bullish       Bearish            32            NaN
8    Bullish       Bullish            45       7.915750
9    Bullish       Bullish            37     -14.662895
10   Bullish       Bullish            46     -99.101387
11   Bullish       Bullish            32      43.625020
12   Bearish       Bullish            30            NaN
13   Bullish       Bearish            36            NaN
14   Bullish       Bullish            16      17.375508
15   Bullish       Bullish            30      11.845724
16   Bullish       Bullish            48       5.978816
17   Bullish       Bullish            48     108.071685
18   Bullish       Bullish            16      23.669653
19   Bearish       Bullish            28            NaN
20   Bullish       Bearish            44            NaN
21   Bullish       Bullish            20  -12112.778236
22   Bearish       Bullish            37            NaN
23   Bullish       Bearish            47            NaN
24   Bullish       Bullish            16     -39.293262
25   Bullish       Bullish            16      -0.436205
26   Bearish       Bullish            34            NaN
27   Bullish       Bearish            21            NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien I need to test your proposal but your results can be right. I made up my column as example. I didn't calculated this values.

Comment: Return this error in pd.DataFrame(): pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: @Optimvs. I updated my answer. The problem is that you have duplicate indexes in your original dataframe. So we can use numpy as a workaround and boolean indexing to set the values. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are passing the entire dataframe like `df['PrevHigh'] or df['Low']` etc in apply method. So you are getting the entire column and hence the error.

You need to pass values from single row. For this you need to use `x['PrevHigh']` instead of `df['PrevHigh']` in the apply method:

Full code:

```
df['Value_Overlap'] = df.apply(lambda x: min((x['PrevHigh'] - x['Low']) / (x['High'] - x['Low']) * 100, (x['PrevHigh'] - x['Low']) / (x['PrevHigh'] - x['PrevLow']) * 100) if x['PrevDirection'] == 'Bullish' and x['Direction'] == 'Bullish' else min((x['High'] - x['PrevLow']) / (x['High'] - x['Low']) * 100, (x['High'] - x['PrevLow']) / (x['PrevHigh'] - x['PrevLow']) * 100) if x['PrevDirection'] == 'Bearish' and x['Direction'] == 'Bearish' else 0, axis=1)
```